# A question about "should" and the past tense

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions

I'm sending a message to my manager.  I don't know if I should send the message to her or to my section head.  At the bottom of the message I want to apologize to my manager if I've sent the message to the wrong person.  I tried this:

> If i shouldn't send the message to you, i am sorry,

Is that correct?

Comment: Remember to capitalize the first-person pronoun `I`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't quite right. It would be more natural to use the present perfect *have sent* instead of *send*, and to use *this message* instead of *the message*.

> If I shouldn't have sent this message to you, I am sorry.

Making these changes makes the sentence grammatically correct. However, there is a more standard way to say what you mean, which may be better.

> I apologize if you are receiving this message in error.

Comment: I wouldn't use "if you are receiving this message in error". That phrase usually implies misaddressing or someone receiving a message that was not sent _to_ them. The message _was_ deliberately sent to the manager, so it's not in error. Perhaps "I apologize if you did not need to receive this message" would be better.